# How to run javascript in android and pass in a map as argument

Tags: javascript, android, rhino, duktape

I'm trying to run javascript in android and found out Rhino and Duktape provides the functionality to run without a WebView.
But it seems like neither of them have a clear way of passing a variable number of key-value pairs as argument into my js function. 
The argument would look like:

```
{"device":"android", "version":"4.4", "country":"US",...}
```

and the js side would look like

```
function calculate(param) {
    var country = 'country';
    var device = 'device';

    if (country in param && param[country]=='US') {
        return "a";
    }; 
    if (device in param && param[device]=="android") {
        return "b";
    } else {
        return "c";
    }
}
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and I get the expected results:

```
#include "src/duktape.h"

char code[] = "function calculate(param) {"
"    var country = 'country';"
"    var device = 'device';"
"    if (country in param && param[country]=='US') {"
"        return \"a\";"
"    }; "
"    if (device in param && param[device]==\"android\") {"
"        return \"b\";"
"    } else {"
"        return \"c\";"
"    }"
"}"
"calculate({\"device\":\"android\", \"version\":\"4.4\", \"country\":\"US\"});";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  duk_context *ctx = duk_create_heap_default();
  duk_eval_string(ctx, code);
  printf("result is: %s\n", duk_get_string(ctx, -1));
  duk_destroy_heap(ctx);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc duktest.c duktape.c -lm
$ ./a.out 
result is: a
```

Maybe your problem is not in duktape?

Comment: Ah, so what you did is put the calling method and params directly into the evaluate string, that's smart, but won't there be performance issue if I want to run multiple times with the same method but different params?

Comment: @arthur li: I think we are getting closer to your original problem. Could it be that you tried to pass your param argument as a JSON string instead of an object?

Answer (score 1):

If the input is a JSON encoded string you get from elsewhere in your program, you can convert it to a parsed object simply as:

```
duk_push_string(ctx, my_json_argument);
duk_json_decode(ctx, -1);
```

The decoded value will be left on the value stack top. The decode call is not "protected" so it will throw on invalid inputs - if that matters, you should wrap the whole argument parsing and call e.g. into a duk_safe_call().

This is faster (and safer) than doing a `duk_eval_string()` especially if the input isn't fully trusted.